# Access is denied from WinAPI OpenProcess

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

So I decided I want to inject a DLL into a notepad process for educational purposes.

```
IntPtr hProcess = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryWrite | ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryWrite | ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryOperation, false, process.Id);           
_log.Info({0}, new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);
```

This seems to fail with "Access is denied". The strange thing is that `hProcess` is not `IntPtr.Zero` and it looks like a handle. Therefore I 'm not 100% sure whether it really failed or not.

Things I tried are listed as follows.

- starting Visual Studio 2017 as Administrator
- using `Process.EnterDebugMode();`
- other access flags, including `0x001F0FFF`

The whole class is down below (not on paste bin anymore).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Blade.Injector
{
class Injector
{
    private readonly NLog.Logger _log = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, AllocationType flAllocationType, MemoryProtection flProtect);

    [Flags]
    public enum AllocationType
    {
        Commit = 0x1000,
        Reserve = 0x2000,
        Decommit = 0x4000,
        Release = 0x8000,
        Reset = 0x80000,
        Physical = 0x400000,
        TopDown = 0x100000,
        WriteWatch = 0x200000,
        LargePages = 0x20000000
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum MemoryProtection
    {
        Execute = 0x10,
        ExecuteRead = 0x20,
        ExecuteReadWrite = 0x40,
        ExecuteWriteCopy = 0x80,
        NoAccess = 0x01,
        ReadOnly = 0x02,
        ReadWrite = 0x04,
        WriteCopy = 0x08,
        GuardModifierflag = 0x100,
        NoCacheModifierflag = 0x200,
        WriteCombineModifierflag = 0x400
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags processAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int processId);

    [Flags]
    public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
    {
        All = 0x001F0FFF,
        Terminate = 0x00000001,
        CreateThread = 0x00000002,
        VirtualMemoryOperation = 0x00000008,
        VirtualMemoryRead = 0x00000010,
        VirtualMemoryWrite = 0x00000020,
        DuplicateHandle = 0x00000040,
        CreateProcess = 0x000000080,
        SetQuota = 0x00000100,
        SetInformation = 0x00000200,
        QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
        QueryLimitedInformation = 0x00001000,
        Synchronize = 0x00100000
    }        

    private const string DllFile = @"C:\Poison.dll";

    public void List()
    {
        var processes = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle)).ToList();

        foreach (var process in processes)
        {
            _log.Info("{0} -> {1}", process.MainWindowTitle, process.Id);
        }
    }

    public bool Inject(int pid)
    {                                       
        Process.EnterDebugMode();

        Process process = Process.GetProcessById(pid);                        

        foreach (ProcessModule module in process.Modules)
        {
            if (module.FileName.Equals(DllFile))
            {
                _log.Info("{0} already inside process.", module.FileName);
                return false;
            }
        }

        _log.Info("Opening process. Last Win32 error is now '{0}'.", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);
        IntPtr hProcess = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryWrite | ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryWrite | ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryOperation, false, process.Id);           
        _log.Info("Opening process resulted in message '{0}'.", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);

        _log.Info("Allocating memory for dll file.");            
        IntPtr allocAddress = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(DllFile.ToCharArray()), AllocationType.Commit, MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);
        _log.Info("Allocating memory for '{0}' resulted in '{1}'.", DllFile, new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);

        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        foreach (ProcessModule module in process.Modules)
        {
            if (module.FileName.Equals(DllFile))
            {
                _log.Info("Success! {0} inside process.", module.FileName);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

}
}
```

- How do I make sure that the message in `new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message)` has something to do with my last call? Maybe something else failed?
- How do I open the process without having access denied messages?
- How do I know whether the `OpenProcess()` method worked in C#? Is checking `hProcess` for not being `IntPtr.Zero` OK?

Comment: Show your declaration for `OpenProcess`.  Did you use the `SetLastError = true` argument in your declaration?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, I linked my fully working class, see https://pastebin.com/wvQftY97.

Comment: `ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryWrite | ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryWrite` seems unnecessary.

Comment: @itsme86: My bad, one of the flags is for reading.

Comment: @TonyStark No, you made a mistake with that by accident... should be `ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryRead | ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryWrite` then, but check what you did and you'll see difference. Currently the code you put in original post does it for write twice via bitmask.

Comment: @ImmortaleVBR: I know but one of the flags is *meant* to be for reading. I corrected it and get same results.

Comment: The function succeeded if it returned a non zero value. No reason to call GetLastError. And please don't provide code in off site links. [mcve] here please.

Comment: If a function is documented as using `GetLastError()` for error reporting, and the function *succeeds*, the value returned by `GetLastError()` is arbitrary and meaningless (unless documented otherwise), usually coming from an *earlier* API call. *Most* API functions do not reset `GetLastError()` before during their work (*some* do)

Comment: What process are you trying to open a handle to? Is the targeted process running as standard rights/admin rights? Are you running as standard rights or administrator (your program)? What OS are you running? What security software do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first place to find an answer to

> How do I know whether *(any function)* worked?

is going to be in the documentation page for that function.  For `OpenProcess()`, the documentation page is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess

Among other things, that page contains the following statements:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is an open handle to the specified process.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

Applying basic logic to the second statement, we conclude that

- If the return value is not NULL, the function did not fail.

Therefore, comparing the return value to `IntPtr.Zero` is OK and actually the best thing to do.

Also note that "To get extended error information, call GetLastError." is subordinate to "If the function fails".  If the function succeeded, there's no detailed error information, so you have no reason to call `GetLastError` and no way to interpret its result if you do call it.

Comment: @TonyStark: The documentation tells you "If the function fails... call GetLastError".   You don't need to call it if the function didn't fail.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I checked again I get a number (looks like a handle) and "access is denied". I expected IntPtr.Zero and "access is denied".

Comment: @TonyStark: If you got a non-zero pointer, then OpenHandle worked.  The "last error" code of 5 (access is denied) may have come from some other operation (prior or intermediate, we don't know), but it should not be interpreted as the outcome of OpenHandle.

Comment: @TonyStark: There is no error (other than calling `GetLastError` when it isn't documented to return a useful value). What are you interested in finding out? The API call succeeded, so move on.

Comment: @IInspectable: Calling `GetLastError()` is not even an error.  It's pointless, and trying to assign meaning to it is an error.  But the function call itself is perfectly harmless.